# Stop zooming when I film

Tags: iphone, camera, zoom

I want to film myself with my iphone, when I'm drawing. The iphone is not moving, and are about 30 cm ≈ 11" above my desk. My paper is on my desk, I sometimes change paper. But when I do so, or even when my hands are moving, the camera "zooms in" on my hands, and then the drawing gets blurry for a second. That's not nice to watch. So, is there a way (or an app or jailbreak) to disable this?

Answer (score 1):

By just holding my finger on the screen, it applies AE/AF lock.

Comment: To clarify a bit, as it says on page 78 of the iPhone User Manual (for iOS7), "To lock the exposure and focus until you tap the screen again, touch and hold until the rectangle pulses." The full manual (big PDF) is here: http://manuals.info.apple.com/MANUALS/1000/MA1565/en_US/iphone_user_guide.pdf

Answer (score 0):

<sup>*I presume you're referring to the 'zoom' effect from autofocus…*</sup>

[**FiLMiC Pro**](http://filmicpro.com/?page_id=4) lets you lock the focus whilst filming.

> The four buttons on the left enable the FiLMiC Pro user to lock and unlock focus, exposure, white balance, and control a full time torch

[image: FiLMiC Pro on iPhone]